# Creating nuget packages for framework projects

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-spec

We have more than 70 projects for our framework and we would like to create nuget packages for all of them. In order to do that we identified the hierarchy of dependencies of those 70 projects and found that we have 4 levels down reference between the projects.

While creating the package low level projects we dont have any issues as they are not dependent on any other projects.

1. But when we go to second level we are facing issue, because level 2 projects will refer the level 1 project's packages and we are confused with level 2 packages should include the binaries of level 1 or they just need to have them as dependencies in the nuspec file, so when the level2 packages installed the level1 dependacies also installed at consumer applications.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your level 2's shouldn't contain the binaries of level 1, just the dependencies in the nuspec file/project.json file.

An example would be the [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) package (or almost any NuGet package really). It has a dependency on quite a few other packages (System.IO, System.Runtime etc), but doesn't include them in the nupkg file - you can open the file for yourself to check.

Comment: Another pro argument for not including any dependencies is that you can update them separately.